Segmentation Fault Streamlit
I try to build a simple Streamlit project with these codes and libraries,
`import streamlit as st 
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu 


import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


st.set_page_config(page_title= '''A/B Tests''', layout= 'wide')



tabs = ['Tab1', 'Tab2', 'Tab3']


with st.sidebar:
    selected = option_menu(
        menu_title = 'Menu',
        options = tabs,
        icons = ['house-heart-fill', 'calendar2-heart-fill', 'envelope-heart-fill'],
        menu_icon = 'heart-eyes-fill',
        default_index= 0
    ) 



i want to add my project a good looking side bar or navigation or something like it.  And as you can see i ve install streamlit_option_menu to my virtual env .
After all this, i write on terminal, "streamlit run app.py" and terminal says to me
"zsh: segmentation fault  streamlit run apps.py"
When I write same code on windows it work but it not work on macOS Bigsur 11.7.10
How can I fix it ?
I m try to upgrade my streamlit version, streamlit_option_menu version for virtual env. After this, i uninstalled to python and other related thing from my computer, re-install again but nothings has change.
I try other 3rd party libraries, i faced same issue. But if I not import to 3rd party libraries, it work.

what  3rd party libraries do you means? How did you install them? Maybe they are not for your system/CPU. MacOS may need different files than Windows.

I mean, actually ı use wrong word . I referred to streamlit_option_menu . ı have installed it as “pip3 install streamlit-option-menu” and the local host down

error like zsh: segmentation fault usually suggests problem with some C/C++ code but I saw GitHub with streamlit-option-menu and there are only .py, .js, .ts, .vue which shouldn't make problem. Without longer error message it is impossible to say what makes problem. First I would check if project still works without streamlit-option-menu  - it could confirm that problem is streamlit-option-menu. And you could run without filterwarnings to see if it shows some information in warnings.
